# Array of hex values to create buttons and pass it's hex values to a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have an array with hex values. I want to be able to create colour swatches and to be able to pass the hex value to a function with an onClick event.

This is my code. But it doesn't work (Even the colour swatches are not showing up).

```
<script>
colVal = ["#454545", "#cccccc", "#ff6600"];
for(var i = 0; i < colVal.length; i++) {
    $("body").append('<input class="colBtn" id="cp"+i type="button" style="background-color:' + colVal[i] + ';  onclick="colChg(' + colVal[i] + ')"/>');
}

function colChg(cVal) {
    //doSomething
}
</script>
```

css

```
.colBtn {
    border: 0.5px outset #000;
    height:25px;
    width:75px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three reasons that doesn't work *(but see below; you're using jQuery, so you don't need to use `onClick` attributes)*:

1. `... id="cp"+i type=...` will put the `+i` in your HTML. You meant `... id="cp' + i + '" type=...` (but do you really need an `id` at all?).
2. `...onclick="colChg(' + colVal[i] + ')...` fails to put quotes around the color value in the JavaScript, resulting in a syntax error. This puts the quotes in: `...onclick="colChg(\'' + colVal[i] + '\')...`
3. You're missing the closing HTML quote on your `style` attribute, so the `onClick` doesn't get noticed. `... + colVal[i] + ';  onclick=...` should be `... + colVal[i] + ';"  onclick=...` (and you don't need the `;` there).

[Working copy with the edits above](http://jsbin.com/zukamu/1):

```
var colVal = ["#454545", "#cccccc", "#ff6600"];
for(var i = 0; i < colVal.length; i++) {
  $("body").append('<input class="colBtn" id="cp' + i + '" type="button" style="background-color:' + colVal[i] + '"  onclick="colChg(\'' + colVal[i] + '\')"/>');
}

function colChg(cVal) {
  // do something
}
```

---

But as you're using jQuery, you can do this much more succinctly and (more importantly) without all the fiddly quotes: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/zukamu/2)

```
$.each(["#454545", "#cccccc", "#ff6600"], function(i, color) {
  $('<input class="colBtn" type="button">')
    .attr("id", "cp" + i)           // (If you need it)
    .css("background-color", color)
    .click($.proxy(colChg, null, color))
    .appendTo(document.body);
});

function colChg(cVal) {
  // Do something
}
```

(The [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) call creates a function that, when called, will call `colChg` with no particular `this` value and with the color.)

---

Side note: Your code falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you never declare your `colVal` variable. Add a `var` in front of it.